# Comma rules for sentence adverb placed in the middle of the sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, adverbs

Why writer has not used comma before or to join these two independent clauses.
"Had anyone actually told her that or had she merely assumed it?"

Comment: Don't you think that depends entirely on what the writer hopes to emphasise?

"Had anyone actually told her that or had she merely assumed it?" would prolly be better with a comma in "that, or" and how is that certain without a wider context, please?

Answer (score 1):

You're right.  Using [a comma after a coordinating conjunction](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CoordConj.html), like "or," when it introduces a second independent clause, like it does in your example, is standard.  You're never wrong to do that.

However, grammar does provide that if both independent clauses are "[very short](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CoordConj.html)," then you may forgo the comma.  Of course, the precise meaning of "very short" is unclear.  That makes the length of "very short," to some degree, a judgment call.

If we are giving the writer the benefit of the doubt, then we would presume that the writer surmised that those independent clauses were both "very short" and so felt it appropriate to exercise the option of forgoing the comma.

Comment: Thanks Billy. Could you confirm that it has nothing to do with sentence adverb 'actually' used in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: @Billy how do you know the conduction isn't *or* but *that*?

Comment: @NeerajV - I can confirm that for Billy.  "Actually" has nothing to do with the comma.

Comment: @aesking - Because "or" is a coordinating conjunction, the only conjunction in that sentence as "that" isn't being used as a conjunction but as a pronoun representing what was said.

Comment: By the way, this answer is 100% correct, which is why I didn't put my own answer.